# Discord.py reupload image

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, python-3.6, discord.py

> The library I'm using is the discord.py rewrite

So I'm making a meme feature on my server, and I've encountered a problem. The problem comes because of my algorithm.

When a user sends image to #memes:

1. Create and embed with link of that attachment
2. Send embed
3. Delete user's message

And after some time, the link expires, and it looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7n8w.png).

I know what I have to do, but I don't know how.
I need the bot to reupload the image and get a cdn.discordapp.com link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I got my bot to reupload the image in an embed

```
@bot.command()
async def attach(self, ctx):
    f = await ctx.message.attachments[0].to_file()
    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.set_image(url=f"attachment://{f.filename}")
    await channel.send(file=f, embed=embed)
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Attachment.to_file

Comment: It's a little odd to see `bot.command` with `self`.  Is this inside a `Cog`?